# HTML5 Navigation Timing API with dynamic content

Tags: jquery, html, navigation-timing-api

I would like to know if dynamic content has any effect on the timing values like loadEnd etc. For example, I conditionally change 'src' attribute of an image in my code using jquery, after loading the page. How is this handled? I tried testing it by checking the values before and after I load the image, it doesn't look like the values change after this image is loaded.
Does that mean the navigation timing API does not include dynamic content loading?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657849/can-i-use-the-browser-navigation-timing-api-for-ajax-events-in-single-page-apps?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The value of the [`loadEventEnd`](http://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/#dom-performancetiming-loadend) [NavigationTiming](http://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/) property is set once the document's `load` event has fired and returns:

> loadEventEnd attribute
>
> This attribute must return the time when the load event of the current document is completed. It must return zero when the load event is not fired or is not completed.

From your statement:

> ... I conditionally change 'src' attribute of an image in my code using jquery, **after loading the page**...

It sounds like you are changing the a `src` attribute either during or after the body's `load` event has fired.  Since the `load` event only ever fires once on a page, the `window.performance.timing.loadEventEnd` property will never change once it is set to a non-zero value.  So it will not reflect the additional time it's taking to download the new `img src`.

If you wanted to include the time that it takes to download the additional image that you're changing the `src` on, you could hook into that image's `load` event. Once that event fires, compare `Date.now()` to [`navigationStart`](http://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/#dom-performancetiming-navigationstart) instead of `loadEventEnd` to get the total elapsed page load time.