# Arraybuffer vs blob performance

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest, blob, arraybuffer

Which has better performance?

I'm getting data and posting it to a different url, I can send both types but which should I choose? The data is a pdf file

Comment: What do you mean by "posting"?

Comment: They mean different things - an arraybuffer is a sequence of raw bytes, while a blob represents a file with an encoding. Since you mention pdf, the latter sounds more appropriate.

Comment: Posting as in sending a post request with the data. I understand that they're different, both of them work for me in my case since I'm not doing anything with the file. My only concern is performance in this case

Comment: Then try both and measure the performance. I'm inclined to guess that they are no different, though.

Comment: How does one accurately measure the performance of ajax calls?

Comment: Just look in the dev tools. Alternatively, log the timestamps of the events related to the ajax call. Or use [performance timing api](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17808655/1048572)

Comment: You're right, virtually no difference in performance, if you post an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which has better performance?

There should be virtually no difference.

> I can send both types but which should I choose for a pdf file?

As a `Blob` does represent a file with an encoding (and is superclass to named `File`s), it seems more appropriate here than an `ArrayBuffer` which is a raw sequence of bytes.